# Java LocalTime value is not correct, when query is using hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, localtime

The question is when I save the value between "12:00 AM"~"8:15 AM" in DB, and query the data using hibernate, it will automatically adding 5 mins.
I have tried using hibernate nativeQuery, it is worked. The value is correct, but when I use Query, the value will be wrong (adding 5 mins when the time value is between "12:00 AM"~"8:15 AM")

My environment is using spring boot 2, hibernate 5 and java1.8
'st1' is the field of the DB(SQL server) saving the time value between "12:00 AM"~"8:15 AM"  in type "time(7)"

```
@Entity
@Table(name="class")
@NamedQuery(name="Class.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Class c")

public class Class extends BaseBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
...
    private LocalTime st1;

    private LocalTime st2;

    private LocalTime st3;

...
}
```

DB part

```
    @Transactional
    public ClassInfoModel getClass(Integer classRef){
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("select c from Class c "
                + "join fetch c.subject s "
                + "join fetch c.refCampus ca "
                + "where c.classRef=:classRef");
        query.setInteger("classRef", classRef);
        List<com.bean.Class> result=query.getResultList();
        return (com.bean.Class) (result.size()==0?null:result.get(0));
   }
```

Comment: This is speculative: Are you in Asia/Shanghai time zone? On January 1 1901 Shanghai changed from GMT offset +08:05:43 (local mean time) to +08:00. If your database or database driver uses a time on that date to transfer the value, then a bug in the same driver or in Hibernate could cause a discrepancy of 5 minutes 43 seconds. And possibly only until 08:05:43 (which is close to the 08:15 that you mentioned).

Comment: yes, as you said, my value is added 00:05:43. when i check the sql server DB time zone and java.util.calendar time-zone that is showing 'China Standard Time'

Comment: That indeed seems to confirm that we’re on the right track. How to work around it, I am sorry, I don’t know.

Comment: is the root cause related with hibernate time zone ? when I set UTC in hibernate, it changed all the data.........

Comment: I have tried changing hibernate jdbc timezone from asia/shanghai to Etc/GMT-8, it turn out all the result to be added 05:43

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it seem to be jvm `System.setProperty("user.timezone", "Asia/xxxx");` is not matched with hibernate jdbc timezone `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=Asia/xxxx;` After align that, it seem to go back to normal, Thanks Ole V.V.

Comment: using tomcat that need to be set catalina_opts=-Duser.timezone=Asia/xxxx